# is it possible word animation falling characters one by one from top to middle in android?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am tried to for android word characters animation falling characters from top to middle in the layout one by one. i don't have any idea being fresher to android development?
please any one can help me in this issue?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a textView for every char and then animate the textViews as you wish. In your sample, you can also have a emtpy textView and anytime an animation finished(single char textView) you can than add or remove from this last textView.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this.Either you can use `translate animation` or `frame animation`. In translate animation, you'll have to take textview for each letter and then translate them as mentioned in Canberk's answer or you find animated `gif` of alphabets and then extract frames from them and use those frames in app to perform frame animation.